# Stata: Test if fixed effects are needed

Tags: chi-squared-test, fixed-effects-model, f-test

In Stata, what is the command I should use to test if fixed effects are needed in my panel data regression?

The output to test for redundant fixed effects should be

Cross-section F-Test

Cross-section Chi-square

But I don't know what command to use.

Thank you

Comment: I answered this question yesterday (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144965/redundant-fixed-effects-test).  My answer should have provided you with enough direction on how to search (e.g. in Google) for the command you need.  Your asking the question a second time suggests you did not put in any effort to search Google.  I can guarantee that if you searched for fixed effects tests in Stata in Google, you will find what you need

Comment: Hi,I certainly did search on Google, but I really couldn't find the Stata command

Comment: I only found a Chow test, which uses test after doing the reg, but this only gives a F-Stat